# How to reopen a question?

Tags: support, closed-questions, reopen-request

If a question is closed but then later the edited, how do you go about re-opening it?

I came across [Unable to open Outlook 2010 on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/818346/unable-to-open-outlook-2010-on-windows-7) in one of the review queues.  Originally, the question was basically just "Outlook won't open".  So I posted a comment asking for more details.  The asker responded, but not before his question was closed as "Unclear what you're asking for".

I edited his question to include the information, but I can't go about answering it because it's closed.  What's the process getting questions back up for a re-open review?  Not just for this question, but closed questions in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing should do the trick, it'll get in the queue. In *theory* you can flag it for mod attention, but looking at the question as it is, I'm kind of ambivalent over its fate. Googling suggests a few things but as it is, we don't know what she's thrown at a wall and has stuck.

Comment: Granted. It's certainly not a stellar question.  But it is a legitimate question; one which might be difficult for an unsophisticated user to know how to phrase in a Google query.

Comment: @WesSayeed - **If you know its not a stellar question then make it one.**